# Neural network classifier always outputs the same class

Tags: pytorch, neural-network, torch, bert-language-model, recommendation-engine

I'm coding a neural network for recommendation system using pytorch. The item's metadata is a textual description and user's metadata are age and gender (binary values). I used Bert encoder (with frozen weights) to extract a vector from item's description (outputs 768-dimensional vector) and two embedding layers for age and gender (each output 10-dimensional vector). Then I concat these to make a 788-dimensional vector and feed it to a 2-layer MLP with a softmax head. The problem is when I train the network, it always outputs class 1. I also rebalanced the data to have the same number of training instances for each class. What may be the problem with this network?